# How to delay a for loop without freezing the UI

Tags: swift, for-loop, freeze

I am currently working on a sorting visualizer, but I need my for loop to "run slower", since I would like to visualize slowly how an algorithm works, for example, bubble sort.

This is my code

```
    func bubbleSort(array: inout [Rectangle], view: UIView) {
    for i in 1 ... array.count {
        for j in 0 ..< array.count - i {
            changeRectColor(rect: array[j])
            changeRectColor(rect: array[j+1])

            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)


            if (array[j].height > array[j+1].height){
                sortRectColor(rect: array[j])
                sortRectColor(rect: array[j+1])
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)

                rectGenerator.removeRectangleView(view: view, tag: array[j].rectView.tag)
                rectGenerator.removeRectangleView(view: view, tag: array[j+1].rectView.tag)

                let temp = array[j].xPos
                array[j].xPos = array[j+1].xPos
                array[j+1].xPos = temp

                rectGenerator.regenerateRectangleView(rect: &array[j], view: view)
                rectGenerator.regenerateRectangleView(rect: &array[j+1], view: view)


                array.swapAt(j, j+1)
            }

            returnRectColor(rect: array[j])
            returnRectColor(rect: array[j+1])

            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)   
        }
    }
}
```

But if I do this, `sleep()` freezes my UI, and it does not show the process.

How can I do something similar but without freezing the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timer  e.x for 1 second delay

```
var counter = 0
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
   guard counter < array.count else { timer.invalidate() ; return }
   // do job
   counter += 1
 }
```

Comment: You mean, using a timer instead of using a for-loop?

Comment: But this will execute the code inside every 1 second, instead of running after reading all lines of code, doesn't it?

Comment: yes and you can change that second to what you need

Comment: But I believe I cannot replace my for-loop with this, because it will not finish the inside code before calling the timer again. For example, if I I do print(counter), things like this may happen: //0 1 1 2 2 2 3...